# Почему так много -m state --state INVALID пакетов в легитимных соединениях?

Tags: linux, tcp, iptables, tcp-ip, firewall

Я читал много статей по настройке iptables, там говорилось, что INVALID пакеты какие-то неправильные и их надо блокировать через -j DROP.

Когда я это сделал, заметил, что легитивные соединения начали обрываться и посыпались жалобы о проблемах с соединением. Действительно, я обнаружил, что INVALID пакетов много бывает в легитимных соединениях, и, если их дропать, то соединение может оборваться.

Вот примеры этих пакетов из лога, это 100% легитимные пакеты от белого айпи:

```
Jun  7 16:49:23 host5 kernel: Iptables: Invalid: IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=1c:b7:2c:ab:e1:a7:e4:c7:22:73:da:a1:08:00 SRC=194.44.28.67 DST=151.80.251.135 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=21078 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51655 DPT=25565 WINDOW=513 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Jun  7 16:49:23 host5 kernel: Iptables: Invalid: IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=1c:b7:2c:ab:e1:a7:e4:c7:22:73:da:a1:08:00 SRC=194.44.28.67 DST=151.80.251.135 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=21099 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51655 DPT=25565 WINDOW=513 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Jun  7 19:09:50 host5 kernel: Iptables: Invalid: IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=1c:b7:2c:ab:e1:a7:e4:c7:22:73:da:a1:08:00 SRC=194.44.28.67 DST=151.80.251.135 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=45401 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63174 DPT=25565 WINDOW=513 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Почему они возникают? И что же все таки с ними делать?
Дропать я их не могу, но и не дропать я тоже не могу, потому что иногда бывают tcp атаки с кучей INVALID пакетов :(

Comment: А это у вас торрент соединения  похоже? 

INVALID пакеты это пакеты которые ни NEW ни ESTABLISHMENT ни RELATED, насколько я помню. Соответственно ежели у вас соединение как вы выражаетесь - легитимные, то внезапно стать в статус INVALID возможно они могут из за каких либо системных ограничений ? Сложно сказать. В любом случае становится Invalid внезапно они не должны. Возможно в какой то момент iptables перестает понимать что это за пакеты ? Почему ? Не знаю. Не изменяли ли вы, например MTU?

Comment: На счет неправильности пакетов - это не совсем так. Они правильные с точки зрения функциональности, просто они не относятся к легитимному (давайте уж этим термином :) ) взаимодействию между вашей системой и внешним интернетом. Ну т.е. куда то приходит какой то пакет, но не по протоколу, например.

Comment: @zalex это не торрент, вообще у меня майнкрафт сервер. я не менял MTU, только iptables настраивал

Comment: Посижу, послежу. Вдруг кто ответит все же. Интересная ситуация. Сам к сожалению не подскажу.

Comment: @zalex если у вас есть свои хосты linux, можете тоже провести эксперимент. Просто логгируйте Invalid пакеты, вот готовое правило, логи будут в /var/log/syslog: iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -m state —state INVALID -m limit —limit 10/s —limit-burst 10 -j LOG —log-prefix "Iptables: Invalid: "

Comment: В данный момент у меня ничего нет через что бы ходил трафик. На самом деле я бы поступил чуть по другому. Я бы перед сервером поставил какой нить недорогой бу микротик с портами  по 100 мегабит. Думаю он обошелся бы совсем недорого, а в работе весьма удобен.

Comment: Я тут по амбару помёл, кстати говори и нашел у себя RB750.  Если интересно - напиши в телеграмм на ник @kolbasyatin, вышлю по адресу совершенно безвоздмездно, т.е. даром :)

Comment: @zalex а зачем это делать? что это даст? у меня вообще ovh хосты, ставить перед ними что-то я не знаю зачем

Comment: Ну перед виртуалкой возможно действительно незачем. Даст то что вы делегируете отдельному устройству функции которые он выполняет. Ну да не  этот вариант.